# After declaring war against city state unable to send envoy later in the game

Tags: civilization-6

Early in the game by mistake, I attacked Brussels troops and so I was at war with Brussels. But now sending an envoy to Brussels is disabled. So will it remain disabled throughout the game, or after a certain number of turns, I will be able to send an envoy to Brussels? I need Brussels suzeranship for 15% extra speed in wonder construction.

Answer (score -1):

To send envoys to city-states, presuming you have envoys to send, you must:

- have met the city-state and be able to interact with them in the city-state panel. If you meet them on the turn roll-over, this may take a turn.
- not be at war with the city-state
- not be at war with the city-state's suzerain (which makes you be at war with the city-state)

If these conditions are met, you can send an envoy to the city-state. If you are at war with a city-state, you can declare peace with them according to the normal rules by interacting with them in the city-state panel. Note that this is not possible if you are at war with their suzerain.

Comment: well even at peacetime, sending envoy is blocked

Comment: Interesting. Could you send a screenshot of that city-state's panel, respectively give more information? I have the feeling this isn't working as intended.